# Python Regex - non-greedy match does not work

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, non-greedy

I have a flat file with one C++ function name and part of its declaration like this:

```
virtual void NameSpace1::NameSpace2::ClassName1::function_name1(int arg1) const
void function_name2
void NameSpace2::NameSpace4::ClassName2::function_name3
function_name4
```

I am trying to extract the function names alone by using this line:

```
fn_name = re.match(":(.*?)\(?", lines)
```

I can understand why `function_name2` and `function_name4` do not match (because there is no leading `:`. But I am seeing that even for `function_name1` and `function_name3`, it does not do non-greedy match. The output of `fn_name.group()` is

```
:NameSpace2::ClassName1::function_name1
```

I have three questions:

1. I expected just the string "`function_name1`" to be extracted from line 1, but the non-greedy match does not seem to work. Why?
2. Why is line 3 not being extracted?
3. How do I get the function names from all the lines using a single regex?

Please help.

Comment: are you aware that `re.match` matches starting from the beginning of the string? None of your strings begin with a colon. Have you tried `re.search` instead?

Comment: Also lazy matching doesn't influence the place, where the regex starts matching - it only influences the end of the match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works pretty well, with your example at least:

```
^(?:\w+ +)*(?:\w+::)*(\w+)
```

i.e., in Python code:

```
import re

function_name = re.compile(r'^(?:\w+ +)*(?:\w+::)*(\w+)', re.MULTILINE)
matches = function_name.findall(your_txt)

# -> ['function_name1', 'function_name2', 'function_name3', 'function_name4']
```

Takeaway: If you can do it with greedy matching, do it with greedy matching.

---

Note that `\w` is **not correct** for a C identifier, but writing down the technically correct character class that matches those is besides the question. Find and use the correct set of characters instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 3):

1) Always use `r" "` strings for regexes.

2)

> I am trying to extract the function names alone by using this line:
>
> ```
> fn_name = re.match(":(.*?)\(?", lines)
> ```
>
> The output of fn_name.group() is
>
> ```
> :NameSpace2::ClassName1::function_name1
> ```

I'm not seeing that:

```
import re

line = "virtual void NameSpace1::NameSpace2::ClassName1::function_name1(int arg1) const"

fn_name = re.search(r":(.*?)\(?", line)
print(fn_name.group())

--output:--
:
```

In any case, if you want to see how non-greedy works, look at this code:

```
import re

line = "N----1----2"

greedy_pattern = r"""
    N
    .*
    \d
"""

match_obj = re.search(greedy_pattern, line, flags=re.X)
print(match_obj.group())

non_greedy_pattern = r"""
    N
    .*?
    \d
"""
match_obj = re.search(non_greedy_pattern, line, flags=re.X)
print(match_obj.group())

--output:--
N----1----2
N----1
```

The non-greedy version asks for all the characters matching `.*` up until the first digit that is encountered, while the greedy version will try to find the longest match for `.*` that is followed by a digit.

3) Warning! No regex zone!

```
func_names = [
"virtual void NameSpace1::NameSpace2::ClassName1::function_name1(int arg1) const",
"void function_name2",
"void NameSpace2::NameSpace4::ClassName2::function_name3",
"function_name4",
]

for func_name in func_names:
    name = func_name.rsplit("::", 1)[-1]

    pieces = name.rsplit(" ", 1)

    if pieces[-1] == "const":
        name = pieces[-2]
    else:
        name = pieces[-1]

    name = name.split('(', 1)[0]
    print(name)

--output:--
function_name1
function_name2
function_name3
function_name4
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I expected just the string "function_name1" to be extracted from line 1, but the non-greedy match does not seem to work. Why?

This is the result from your regex [":(.*?)\(?"](https://regex101.com/r/gU3uO1/2)

I think your regex is **"Too Lazy"**. It will match only `:` because `(.*?)` stand for match any characters **"as less as possible"** then regex engine chooses to match **zero character**. It will not match till `\(?` as you expected because `?` just means **"optional"**.

> 2. Why is line 3 not being extracted?

As I've tested your regex. It doesn't work at all not only the third line.

> 3. How do I get the function names from all the lines using a single regex?

You can start from this minimal example

```
(?:\:\:|void\s+)(\w+)(?:\(|$)|(function_name4)
```

Where `(?:\:\:|void\s+)` represents to anything that leading your function name and `(?:\(|$)` represents to anything that follow you function name.

Note that `function_name4` suppose to be declared explicitly due to lacking of pattern.

see: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gU3uO1/3)

Answer (score 0):

I've been stumped before by something similar when trying to capture the "N----1" from "N foo bar N----1----2".  Adding a leading .* gave the desired result.

```
import re
line = "N foo bar N----1----2"
match_obj = re.search(r'(N.*?\d)', line)
print(match_obj.group(1)) 

match_obj = re.search(r'.*(N.*?\d)', line)
print(match_obj.group(1))

--output:--
N foo bar N----1
N----1
```